# Programmatically bind instance of class to qualifier in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have instances of the same class being created from config values such that I need them to be injected/autowired from that config value. I was doing it in `guice` like:

```
for (String s : config.getStrings()) {
    bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(s)).toInstance(new Foo(s));
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this in `Spring` or is there a way to use something like a `FactoryBean` to create instances of a class given a `qualifier`?

Comment: Can you be please explain the problem statement a bit more. It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public final class FLEXSyncFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static AbstractApplicationContext context;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    throws BeansException {
        context = (AbstractApplicationContext) applicationContext;
    }
```

And to register alias of bean

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();
Foo fooBean = beanFactory.getBean(Foo.class);
beanFactory.initializeBean(fooBean, "TheAliasForBeanNameYouNeed");
beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(fooBean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
```

Comment: This answer got me there. All I needed was context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(fooBean, instance) and then it was autowireable by @Qualifier("fooBean")